Databricks Scala Read Parquet files
I am reading multiple parquet files, I am creating a manual schema to load data into dataframe. While loading the data, I am getting the error Cannot convert parquet type DOUBLE to Photon Type String
val test=spark.read.schema(Schema).path(xyz)
